# Support Fragment With popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im currently working on a BottomViewNavigation Android app. I have 3 navigations at the bottom bar (something like Instagram bottom bar). Lets name them as A, B and C.

In B, I am loading a recycler view with data from the server. On B viewCreated, the async will run with a ProgressDialog and populate multiple cardViews. Once loaded, I can click a cardView to view the full details in a new fragment, lets say B_1. Also when I click the cardView, I am adding addToBackStack so that when i click hardware back button, it will bring me back to B and reload the list.

Problem happens when I am in B_1, and I click bottom bar A.

Of course, I did try popBackStack everytime A, B or C is clicked. When I click A and remove all backstacks, B is resuming on the popping process, causing the ProgressDialog of B to show up for a little while before Fragment A is displayed.

I tried searching all around for a proper implementation of fragments with backstack without having the previous view to pop up, unfortunately couldnt find any work around for this. I did try popBackStackImmediate, no good. I did try with .POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE, no good.

Seeking for advice on how we can pop it without resuming, or remove the backstacks one shot without loading, or any ways that we can look at. Help is much appreciated.

Adding backstack on cardView adapter click:

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new B_1()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Popping backstack in MainActivity before transaction of A, B, C:

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, fragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
```

Comment: Just to help me get context to your case.. Why are you popping the backstacks when you change BottomNavigation tab?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im popping the backstacks because if I change tab, and I click back button on the device, its bringing me back to B_1, which in some cases B_1 will not have the data to display as data is passed from B.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to just keep separate back stacks for each tab? So that changing a tab doesn't mess up the other tabs back stacks?